# Forum submission requires double submit before doing anything

Tags: php, forms, action

So this might be because of my action but at the same time I doubt it, how ever I am confused as to why this happens at all.

I have some php that essentially does this:

```
if($_POST['submit_me']){
    //I am calling some php function here
}

<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit_me' />
</form>
```

When this form is submitted, I must hit the submit button again to get the results of the functions that's being called and I am wondering if its because I should be calling that function through the action?

Comment: placing `<input type='hidden' name='changed' value='1' />` better, i think. and works fine from first time.

Comment: the form action attribute must be the url of the page that is going to process your data, why not try to put something if it will make a difference.

Comment: i just checked this. works fine without `action`.

Comment: If the `if($_POST['submit_me'])` is on the same page as your form, you should not need to reference anything with the `action` attribute in your form, as that determines the URL that the form will be posted to. Does the PHP function you are calling work correctly in other places, or could it be a problem with the function that is preventing it from firing correctly the first time it is called?

Comment: the php function works fine. I will try this hidden form field idea. how ever is that not insecure?